# Showing images by .ashx file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I usualy use thumbnail.ashx file to show images. The problem is if I use it in the index view it works but if I use it in edit view it does not. The src for img tag changes from

```
http://domain/Thumbnail.ashx?id=17 (right)
```

to

```
http://domain/mycontroller/edit/Thumbnail.ashx?id=17 (wrong)
```

do I need to add another route to the table? and what it could be?

Comment: You should use an MVC action instead of an ASHX.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an absolute path (starting with `/`).

Comment: what do you exact mean "absolute path", my code is following, MyImage is a extension method which renders a <imge src=".." /> tag.
 @Html.MyImage("Thumbnail.ashx?id=" + item.id)